# Contour area calculation using matplotlib path

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap, shapely, vertices, contourf

I am trying to calculate the area covered by a specific contour line using matplotlib Path and shapely Polygon functions, the problem in doing this is that my polygon is irregular and has holes in it, and the shapely Polygpon function doesn't know which vertices are exterior and which are interior and hence which should be taken as part of the polygon and which ones should be considered part of gaps. Is there a way to solve this?

[image: Contour obtained using matplotlib pyplot function]

[image: eShapely polygon plot of vertices obtained from the contour with internal areas wrongly considered as gaps]

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=-30,urcrnrlat=30,llcrnrlon=30%360,\
            urcrnrlon=-130%360,lat_ts=20,resolution='c');
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_sst, lat_sst);
x, y = m(lons, lats);
levels=[28.5,np.amax(data)]
cs = m.contourf(x,y,data,levels)
cn = cs.collections[0].get_paths()
vs=[]
for i in range(len(cn)):
    vs.append(cn[i].vertices)
area_of_individual_polygons = []
for i in range(len(vs)):
    area_of_individual_polygons.append(Polygon(vs[i]).area)
total_area = np.sum(area_of_individual_polygons)
```

Comment: Can you please post your `shapely` code as well?

Comment: Hi Thomas, my shapely code is included in the Polygon.area function

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two problems

1. The vertices you deal with are not what you think they are
2. Your contour plot shows 'holes' that you need to *remove* from your total area rather than add in order to get the area of the green shading correct

But let's go from the start. `Axes.contourf()` returns a `QuadContourSet` (which you store in `cs`. This contains all the data that `matplotlib` needs to draw the filled contours. As you have only two levels, `cs.contours` only contains one item, which is a `PathCollection`. With `cs.collections[0].get_paths()` you get a list of paths that describe your polygons. However, if you look closely at your first image, there is a larger green shape (let's call it a landmass) with some smaller white 'holes' in it (let's call them lakes, might be valleys as well) and some smaller green patches off the main land mass (let's call them islands). Now the problem is that the land mass and the lakes are **all one path**, while the islands are separate paths.

The contour of the landmass is defined by first defining the outline in one direction (say clockwise) and then defining the outline of the lakes in the opposite direction (which would then be counter-clockwise). In order for matplotlib to know how to deal with this, the path is broken into pieces using *codes*. Three codes are in use here: `Path.MOVETO` (=1), `Path.LINETO` (=2), and `Path.CLOSEPOLY` (=79). You get a list of these codes with `path.codes` (see below). Each segment starts with a `Path.MOVETO` and ends with a `Path.CLOSEPOLY`, with a lot of `PATH.LINETO`s in between (at least in this case, where there are no curved paths). Each code has a corresponding vertex (which you get with `path.vertices`, only the vertices corresponding to `Path.CLOSEPOLY` are ignored (and usually set to (0,0)), so you must remove them for you final calculations. With the help of these codes, each path is divided into segments.

After telling you all this, what you will need to do is to not only retrieve the vertices from each path, but also the corresponding codes. Then you need to split the codes and vertices into segments (using the codes this is pretty easy) and then compute the area for each of these segments separately. To top it all off, to calculate the area of the shaded area correctly, you have to sum the areas of the respective *first* path segments and subtract the areas of the the other segments. Here is an example how to do this:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

##setup
lonmin, lonmax = 30%360,-130%360
latmin, latmax = -30, 30
lon_sst = np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, 50)
lat_sst = np.linspace(latmin, latmax, 50)
lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lon_sst, lat_sst);

##generating some example data
lonmid = 0.5*(lonmin+lonmax)
latmid = 0.5*(latmin+latmax)
data = (
    10*np.cos(np.deg2rad(lons-lonmid))**2*np.cos(3*np.deg2rad(lats-latmid))**2
    -10*np.exp(-0.01*((lons-(lonmin+2*lonmid)/3)**2+2*(lats-latmid)**2))
    -10*np.exp(-0.01*((lons-(lonmax+2*lonmid)/3)**2+(lats-latmid)**2))
    +10*np.exp(-0.1*((lons-(lonmid+2*lonmax)/3)**2+2*(lats-(latmid+2*latmax)/3)**2))
    )

##opening figure and axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

##do the Basemap stuff
m = Basemap(
    ax=ax,projection='cyl',
    llcrnrlat=-30,    urcrnrlat=30,
    llcrnrlon=30%360, urcrnrlon=-130%360,
    lat_ts=20,resolution='c'
)
x, y = m(lons, lats);
levels=[2,np.amax(data)]
cs = ax.contourf(x,y,data,levels)

##organizing paths and computing individual areas
paths = cs.collections[0].get_paths()
help(paths[0])
area_of_individual_polygons = []
for p in paths:
    sign = 1  ##<-- assures that area of first(outer) polygon will be summed
    verts = p.vertices
    codes = p.codes
    idx = np.where(codes==Path.MOVETO)[0]
    vert_segs = np.split(verts,idx)[1:]
    code_segs = np.split(codes,idx)[1:]
    for code, vert in zip(code_segs,vert_segs):

        ##visualising (not necessary for the calculation)
        new_path = Path(vert,code)
        patch = PathPatch(
            new_path,
            edgecolor = 'black' if sign == 1 else 'red',
            facecolor = 'none',
            lw =1
        )
        ax.add_patch(patch)

        ##computing the area of the polygon
        area_of_individual_polygons.append(sign*Polygon(vert[:-1]).area)
        sign = -1 ##<-- assures that the other (inner) polygons will be subtracted

##computing total area        
total_area = np.sum(area_of_individual_polygons)
formstring = ''.join(['{:+.2}' for a in area_of_individual_polygons])+'={:.2}'
print(formstring.format(*area_of_individual_polygons,total_area))

plt.show()
```

Here is the image that corresponds to the above code. Note that I outlined the areas that are added in *black* and the areas that are subtracted in *red*. Note also, that there are still some corner cases, where this goes wrong (for instance an island inside a lake).

[image: result of above code]

And here is still the output of the `print` command, which is just a visualisation of the calculation that happens in the code:

```
+4.5e+03-3.2e+02-1.9e+02+4.3e+01=4e+03
```

Hopefully this clears it up.